# I downloaded from the server Json but do not know its size and structure

Tags: android, json

I do parsing JSON

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl() {

    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

        String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
                ("estafeta@62e12548-0a68-4999-960b-a3bb3c44675c:11111")
                        .getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
                "https://test2.estafeta.org/mobileestafeta/MobileSurveyReportsService.svc/LoadTabletSurveyTasks?startRowVersion=AAAAAAAAAAA=&count=500");

        get.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
        //httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}
```

**I downloaded from the server Json but do not know its size and structure**

1)Tell me how I can look at the size and structure of the JSON I received from the server?

2) How can I view the contents of jObj ?

3) What happens and why so many lines?

[image]

Comment: Why not simply type the URL in a browser ? Note that when I tested the server seemed very ill.

Comment: If you click on the link - does not show anything, but you can request

Comment: use Gson instead. Its a lib from google to work efficiently with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The ADT comes with a nifty tool called DDMS. In the upper right corner of your Eclipse IDE, you can find `perspectives`. Pick the DDMS perspective.

Next up, you can enable profiling of your project. Click on your project and press the green bug (debug) button. You can then use the DDMS tabs to go to `Allocation`.

In Allocation, you can find every pointer, and what it's referring to. So you could find your `jObj` variable and view what it's pointing to and every object in it.

Learn how to use the DDMS [with tutorials like these](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/what-is-ddms-and-how-it-works/). They will improve your life.